# Swift - How to populate a dictionary inside a concurrent enumerateObjects block?

Tags: swift, concurrency

Is it possible to populate a dictionary or an array within enumerateObjects(options: .concurrent)? I continue to receive a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to populate the dictionary. It will work when I add a semaphore, however adding a semaphore in front of the dictionary also adds a ton of overhead and defeats the entire purpose of me wanting to use enumerateObjects(options: .concurrent) to improve performance.  Here is the code that I currently have:

```
func parseImgColor(_ cgImage: CGImage){
    
    let yRange = (0..<cgImage.height)
    let yArray: NSArray = yRange.map { $0 } as NSArray

    let xRange = (0..<cgImage.width)
    let xArray: NSArray = xRange.map { $0 } as NSArray
    
    var coordinateMap: [Coordinate : CoordColor] = [:]
    
    yArray.enumerateObjects(options: .concurrent) { yPosition, index, yStopPointer in
        guard let y: Int = yPosition as? Int else {
            yStopPointer.pointee = true
            return
        }
        xArray.enumerateObjects(options: .concurrent) { xPosition, index, xStopPointer in
            guard let x: Int = xPosition as? Int else {
                xStopPointer.pointee = true
                return
            }
            let coords = Coordinate(x: x, y: y)
            if x % 2 == 0{
                coordinateMap[coords] = CoordColor(value: UIColor.blue);
            } else {
                coordinateMap[coords] = CoordColor(value: UIColor.white);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The structs that I'm using to define my dictionary include:

```
struct Coordinate: Hashable {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
}

struct CoordColor: Hashable{
    let value: UIColor
}
```

Sample Image of Failure:
[image]

Comment: Is your code going to be more complicated than this, or is it simply going to generate blue and white "vertical lines" along the y axis?

Comment: You could be collecting the result on a serial `DispatchQueue` but it seems like you're over-engineering it. Just run that code on a single background queue without concurrency.

Comment: Hi Rob I appreciate your comment. Currently I'm running the code on a single background queue, but I want to switch from that and try to use this approach with enumerateObjects concurrently because it loops through an image way faster. And to answer your question Sander, yes the actual code is a lot more complicated and in depth but I didn't want to add pages of meaningless code to stack overflow when the heart of the question remains whether its possible to populate a data structure like an array or dictionary inside an enumerateObjects concurrent block.

Answer (score 0):

If the heavy side of computation happens inside the loop, then maybe collecting the result on a serial queue isn't going to be that bad.

Also, why not zipping both (x,y) ranges together and then using something like `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform()` to parallelize the computation as opposed to using two nested loops that each spawn on concurrent queue?

So here is what I would try to do:

```
// Image size
let width = 3
let height = 4

// Total number of iterations
let iterationCount = width * height

// Your dictionary key
struct Coordinate: Hashable, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int

    var debugDescription: String {
        return "\(x).\(y)"
    }
}

// Spawn on concurrent queue
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    var result: [Coordinate: String] = [:]
    let resultQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "ResultCollectorQueue")

    DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: iterationCount) { i in
        // Compute x,y for the image, however you could also zip xArray and yArray ranges together instead
        let x = i / width
        let y = i % width

        // Do something heavy

        // Collect the result on a serial queue
        resultQueue.async {
            result[Coordinate(x: x, y: y)] = "\(x) \(y)"
        }
    }

    // Pick up the result
    resultQueue.async {
        print("Got result: \(result)")
    }
}
```

There is a great material available on objc.io that dives into implementation of concurrent map: https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E90-concurrent-map